# Magento Checkout Expand Tax (Show: Product and Shipping Tax)

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

In my store in the Checkout I charge taxes for Products and Shipping.
When I click on Total Tax (+ signal), to expand taxes charged, I only see Taxable Goods (15%) which includes a total for Product and Shipping combined.

```
For example 
Subtotal: $50
 Shipping & Handling: $10.00
 Taxable Goods (15%): $9.00 (calculated as follows: $50 + $10 and multiplied by 15%)
 +Tax $9.00 (expand) 
Grand total: $69.00
```

Any ideas how to add Shipping and Handling to expandable tax breakdown ?

Answer (score 0):

Okey, after some time I realized what was the issue. By default in **`Sales-->Tax-->Manage Tax Rules`**  you have two rules Taxable Goods and Shipping, often times they have exactly the same Tax Rates set up in them. 
Now, go to **`Sales-->Tax-->Tax Zones & Rates`** you will find a list of tax rates. For you to be able to expand the TAX in the checkout, and show tax for Product and a sepate field Tax for Shipping you have to create a Separate Tax Rates. it could be an exact copy of your Taxable Goods rate but make sure to call it Shipping Rate, or any other preferred name.
Once you set up separate rates for shipping. Go back to Manage Tax Rules and make sure to choose selected tax rates for the Shipping.

Your checkout will Look similar to this (tax rate 15% in my case)

```
Subtotal: $100
Shipping & Handling: $10
  -Shipping & Handling Tax: $1.50
  -Taxable Goods $15
+Total Tax: $16.5 (expandable with + sign)
Grand Total: $126.5
```

DONE.